# RecyclerView lags while scrolling the page

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-recyclerview

I am using 4 horizontal recyclerviews along with a navigation drawer on the main activity. I am using data from a remote server to populate the recyclerviews and I am using AsyncTask for the data loading.The top 2 recyclerviews scroll fast. However, when I add the other 2 recyclerviews below the first two, my page lags a lot while scrolling.  Even the navigation drawer lags a lot. However, it works well when I have only 2 horizontal recyclerviews. Problem arises only when I add the third and fourth.